# A statement regarding vector spaces....

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L$ be a vector space, and $U,W,V$ subspaces of $L$. Show:

$$U\cap W\subseteq V \iff (U+V)\cap (W+V) =V$$

I've tried the following:

Suppose that $(U+V)\cap (W+V) =V$. Since $0_L\in V$, we have $(U+0_L)\cap (W+0_L) \subseteq V$.

On the other side, suppose that $U\cap W\subseteq V $. How do I continue?

Answer (score 1):

Given: $ U \cap W \subseteq V $

To be proven: $(U+V)\cap (W+V) =V$

Proof: The proof consists of two parts, i.e.

(1) $(U+V)\cap (W+V) \subseteq V$ and 
(2) $V \subseteq (U+V)\cap (W+V) $

Proof (1) $(U+V)\cap (W+V) = (U \cap W) + V$ (by the definition of direct sum? I'm not sure if this is correct.)

$(U \cap W) + V \subseteq V+V = V$ since $(U \cap W) \subseteq V$.

Proof (2) Both $(U+V)$ and $(W+V)$ contain all the vectors $\vec{v} \in V$, thus the intersection $(U+V) \cap (W+V)$ contains all the vectors $\vec{v} \in V$ as well.

I hope this comment is helpful for you.

Comment: You're welcome! Can you do me a favour and upvote my answer (so I get 15 points as reward)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I don't think the identity $(U+V)\cap (W+V) = (U \cap W) +V$ holds for general subspaces. I don't have a counter-example right now, but I recall the lattice of subspaces being non-distributive. Can you provide justification for that perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the statement $(U \cap W) \subseteq V \implies (U+V) \cap (W+V) = V $ is correct? I could find a counterexample in 3D.

Let $U, W$ and $V$ be three planes through the origin that intersect each other in one line $l$.

In that case is $(U \cap W)$, i.e. the intersection line $l$, a subsect of $V$. On the other hand, $U+V = \mathbb{R}^3$ and $W+V = \mathbb{R}^3$, so $(U+V) \cap (W+V) = \mathbb{R}^3 \neq V $$

Can anyone check this?

Comment: @ the community member who upvoted this: thank you for checking this!